# hibernate needs oracle client

Tags: java, hibernate, oracle12c

I am not using Maven. hibernate 5.2, spring framework 4.3.1 and jdk 1.8, tomcat server 7, liferay 4.3.4.
Hibernate connect to Oracle12C 64 bit server with defination in hibernate.properties file.

Do I need also to install Oracle Client 12c 64 bit to Windows Server 2012 that war file is working there?

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate can work with any client. You just have to add oracle driver into hibernate.cfg file.

Add Oracle jar in lib. It will work with any db.

Comment: Narenda and Patel thanks for your comment. There is jboss 4.0.5.and there are jar files in client, lib, server\default\lib directorys. I found 'ojdbc14.jar' in server\...., is it enough this file to connect oracle 12c 64 bit ?

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't. Having the driver jars in the classpath is enough.

You can download the drivers from here:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html

Comment: thanks Andres. what are name of driver jars, you dont now , I will search for control.

Comment: You can download them from here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html

Comment: Andres added 'ojdbc7.jar' instead of 'ojdbc14.jar' to server\lib\ path in jboss 4.0.5 from this link. now I seen first error in log  so update hibernate 5.1 from 3, spring framework 4.3.1. also change hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect.Oracle10gDialect in hibernate .properties file. Error;org.hibernate.HibernateException: unknown Oracle major version [12]

Answer (score 0):

Do the below -

1) check hibernate.cgf.xml(or your hibernate config file) & confirm if they are correct -

```
hibernate.connection.url
hibernate.connection.username
hibernate.connection.password
hibernate.dialect
hibernate.connection.driver_class
```

2) check for the oracle jar file in your lib folder.Like for Jboss it needs to be added in its module folder.(Not sure with tomcat server)